# Real time database rules for newsletter sign up form

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have a single field form on my site to sign up for a newsletter. It asks for the email address and submits it to the Firebase database. I do not want anyone to read it apart from me, and I do not want anyone to be able to update or delete anything from it.

All I want the public to be allowed to do is write an email address to the database.

This is my current rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "emails": {
       "$uid": {  
         ".write": "!data.exists()",
           "mail" : {
             ".validate": "newData.val().matches(/^.*[@].*[.].*$/)"
           }

       }
     }
   }
}
```

This accepts something like:

```
firebase.database().ref('emails').push().set({mail: "test@gmail.com"});
```

and denies something like:

```
firebase.database().ref('emails').push().set({mail: "test"});
```

but still accepts this:

```
firebase.database().ref('emails').push().set({test: "test"});
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to [use a `$` wildcard rule](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#using_variables_to_capture_path_segments) to reject anything else:

```
"$uid": {  
  ".write": "!data.exists()",
    "mail" : {
      ".validate": "newData.val().matches(/^.*[@].*[.].*$/)"
    },
    "$other": {
      ".validate": false
    }
}
```