# Data validation on Realtime Database

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I'm trying to do a simple validation as a test but it's not working, I think I didn't get the syntax. the idea is to store an email on the db, so the first test that i'm trying is to set the length as shown here:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": false,
    ".write": true,
      ".validate": "newData.val().length <= 50"
  }
}
```

With this rules i get permission denied everytime, my db id structured like this, db>infos>random key>email, so I tried this and get the same result:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "infos": {
      "email": {
        ".write":true,
            ".validate": "newData.val().length < 50"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What is the right way to do something like that?(I'm a beginner on web development in general)

On standard rules, when I enter some data on the website it gives me that on the database

[image: Database]

Validation test 1:

[image: Validation test 1] Denied on website and playground

Validation test 2
[image: Validation test 2] Denied on website and passes on the playground

Comment: 1) Please edit your question to show the code that you're using to test the rules with. If you're using the playground for testing, please add a screenshot of the path and value you entered there. 2) There is no way to customize the message returned by the rules. You'll typically check the same condition in your code, and raise the correct/most helpful error message there. Since this has been asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-security%5D%5Bfirebase-realtime-database%5D+customize+message), I recommend removing it to prevent your question from being closed.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I added an image of the playground, I don't now if i'm using correctly. I forgot to add this comment and was trying on the playground. When I execute the second rule that i posted it works fine, but when i try on the website doesn't pass

Comment: Explanation for he difference in playground behavior is below. Since the second example works in the playground but not in your own web site, please edit your question to include the (standalone) code that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The first reject is expected, as you're writing a JSON object to the root and that doesn't have a `length` property.

Remember `newData` is the data as it exists at the location where the rule is defined, so in that case `newData` is your entire database. You'll typically want to define your rules on the level of the data you're validating, like in your second example.

Since the second example works in the playground, please edit your question to include the (standalone) code that doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I found the solution on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62022490/real-time-database-rules-for-newsletter-sign-up-form. But it wasn't clear to me the use of  $uid since I'm not authenticating the user. Is it related with how do I pass the information to the database? Could you explain me this part or point some direction? Again, really thanks for the answer and the patience haha

Comment: Good to hear you found the solution. 